# Remove Speech Marks from file where Text Qualifier is "

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, ssis-2012, data-import

**Introduction**

We have a pretty standard way of importing .txt and .csv into our data warehouse using SSIS.

Our txt/csvs are produced with speech marks as text qualifiers. So a typical file may look like the below:

```
"0001","025",1,"01/01/19","28/12/18",4,"ST","SMITH,JOHN","15/01/19"
"0002","807",1,"01/01/19","29/12/18",3,"ST","JONES,JOY","06/02/19"
"0003","160",1,"01/01/19","29/12/18",3,"ST","LEWIS,HANNAH","18/01/19"
```

We have set all our SSIS packages to strip out the speech marks by setting Text Qualifier = "

**Problem**

However, as some of our data entry is done manually, speech marks are sometimes used - particularly in free text fields such as NAME where people have nicknames/alias. This causes errors in our SSIS loading.

An example of a problematic row would be:

```
"0004","645",1,"01/01/19","29/12/18",3,"ST","MOORE,STANLEY "STAN"","12/04/19"
```

**My question**

Is there a way to somehow strip out these problematic speech marks? i.e. the speech marks surrounding "STAN", so that column would be treated as MOORE, STANLEY STAN.

If there was a way within SSIS to do this, great. If not, we are open to other ideas outside of SSIS.

Solution needs to be scalable as we have hundreds of SSIS packages where this problem can occur.

Comment: If your process is resulting in MOORE,STANLEY "STAN" then simply use derived column and replace([columnName],"""","")

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. I know Excel has a setting that says something like "Treat Consecutive Delimiters as one."
2. Change your delimiter to something else, like a pipe (the thing above the backslash, not sure what it is called elsewhere, looks like a vertical line). You can distinguish delimiters from quote marks that are meant to be included in the resulting value because any string delimiter either immediately precedes or immediately follows a comma. A quote character anywhere else is not a delimiter.
3. If you do not need to pass the data through any T-SQL you might want to replace non-delimiter quotes with single quotes or, depending on the final output, maybe the html entity (`&quot;`) instead.
   Hope this helps,

Joey